# Define constants in another header file with namespace

Tags: c++

### First question

```
//Constants.hh
namespace Constants{
    static double pi;
    static double e;
    // ...
};

//Constants.cc
#include "Constants.hh"
Constants::pi = 3.1415;
Constants::e = 2.72;
// ..
```

If I compile with: `g++ Constants.cc`

I get an error that says that `e` and `pi` in class `Constants` do not name a type.

### Secondo question

I also have:

```
//Angle.hh
class Angle {
public:
static double piatto;
static double retto;
static double giro;
// ...
};

//Angle.cc
#include "Angle.hh"
#include "Constants.hh"
double Angle::retto = Constants::pi / 2;
double Angle::piatto = Constants::pi;
double Angle::giro = Constants::pi * 2;
// ...
```

And a main:

```
#include "Angle.hh"
#include "Constants.hh"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << Constants::pi << "\n\n";
    std::cout << std::endl << Angle::retto << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation is ok, but when I run it, it prints "0" and "0" as the two values. Why?

Comment: you have to provide the type.

Comment: As in `double Constants::pi = 3.1415;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question: as the compiler says, you left the type name out of the definitions:

```
double Constants::pi = 3.1415;
^^^^^^
```

Second question: you've declared the variables `static`, giving them internal linkage. So there will be a separate copy in each translation unit, and that will have the value zero except in the one that contains the initialiser.

Options are:

- initialise them in the header, rather than a separate source file, so they have the same value in all translation units;
- give them external linkage by removing `static` (or replacing it with `extern` if you like).

They should also probably be `const` to enforce their constantness. In that case, they will have internal linkage by default, so you'll need an explicit `extern` if you don't initialise them in the header.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
double Constants::pi = 3.1415;
double Constants::e = 2.72;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use `extern` for global variable declaration, it becomes its implicit definition.